# swing .form не создаются формы

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, form

Возможно вопрос может показаться вопрос тупым и ненужным, но возникла вот такая проблема:

Создал я новую форму, после чего добавил элементов управления (скрин. ниже).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но в Классе самой формы кроме названий этих элементов ничего не создалось.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и При запуске отображается только то, что я прописал в конструкторе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И получается, что мне нужно создавать все элементы в ручную, а из за того, что я немного криворук, то это не есть возможным. Ещё одна причина в том, что нужно ещё и вертикальные и горизонтальные спейсеры добавлять.

И вопрос, как мне загрузить форму и получить все элементы инициализированные (как в NetBeans делается).
Или как ресурс загрузить .form и только поэлемнтно, в ручную инициализировать их?

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDEA, к сожалению, не генерирует корректный код для показа формы. Установка GUI в конструкторе генерируется автоматически при попытке первой сборки, если настройки IDE выставлены правильно. Но, чтобы всё нормально заработало нужно поработать руками.

Для Swing помогает следующий способ:

1. "Назначить" форму наследником класса `Container` (обычно предлагает сама IDE на этапе 2)

   `public class Form1 extends Container`
2. Прописать статический метод, который будет собственно и выводить форму на экран.

   `public static void showForm() {
       JFrame jf = new JFrame("Form1");
       jf.setContentPane(new Form1().panel1);
       jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       jf.pack();
       jf.setVisible(true);
   }`